# Django: Create multiple objects from one view

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am building a website which allows teachers to ask questions to their students, and get answers back from their students.

Each 'review' will consist of a title, description and then a bunch of questions related to the review via a foreign key. The questions would be added one by one and to add more Javascript will be used to add the additional fields.

The way I am currently thinking of doing this by having one view, which first processes a form that creates the Review object with the title, description and User that made it. It would then take all the questions the user had entered create an object for each of these using the ID of the review that was just created.

I made a simple form and a view that makes the Review block, however I dont know how to go about handling the questions the user wants to add.

If there are any other better ways of doing this, please let me know!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your users will be in the Django admin, the inlineModelAdmin is what you are looking for:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin

If this view will be outside of the Django admin you can replicate that functionality with model formsets: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets

They let you create many potential instances of the same model form so you user can create the review object, then create one or many questions related back to the review.

Comment: By 'in the Django Admin' do you mean having access to the Django Admin page and add reviews like so?

Comment: This answer is a bit confused. You don't create inline formsets in the admin, you create an InlineAdmin and Django automatically takes care of the formsets. For the OP's use case, inline formsets *are* what they want, though.

Comment: Sorry about that, I should have re-read my answer. Thank you for adding clarification. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you will have roughly these classes in your models.py:

```
Student
Teacher
Review
Question
```

Therefore it's about setting up the underlying data model to facilitate what you want to implement.  I would suggest that you need to implement many-to-many relationships here to map questions and answers to reviews.
For each review, you would need to join it up to questions so something like:

```
class ReviewQuestions(models.Model):
    questionID = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    reviewID = models.ForeignKey(Review)
    questionNumber = models.IntegerField()
```

should join up the review to a list of questions, you could even add a question number (as per the example above).

To join up the answers you would then need to link each student's answer to a question using something like this:

```
class ReviewQuestionAnswers(models.Model):
    reviewQuestionID = models.ForeignKey(ReviewQuestions)
    studentID = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    answer = models.TextField()
```

of course the answer might be an integer or something else but this structure would mean that for each question on each review you can store an answer for each student.

You should then then be able to render the ReviewQuestions model as it will be linked to the reviewID (so you can get all of the details) and simply add a record for each question that you want to add.